# Multi data in 1 line with reporting service

Tags: reporting-services

I'm beginner reporting service and i have problem.
I have dataset with many borrower like this:

```
Loans           Borrower         DateCreate
-----------------------------------------------
L1              name 1           10/7/2010
L1              name 2           10/7/2010
L1              name 3           10/7/2010
L2              name 4           14/7/2010
L2              name 5           14/7/2010
```

and i want my report like, i can't know how to do.

```
Loans           Borrower                         DateCreate
----------------------------------------------------------------
L1              name 1, name 2, name 3           10/7/2010
L2              name 4, name 5                   14/7/2010
```

can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do this in the underlying dataset (in SQL Server for example). Like these examples

- [Displaying a field as a comma separated list in Reporting Services 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024456/)
- [Concatenate a selected column in a single query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808613)
- [SQL Server reporting services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229071)